# Is there any simple way to add an error class to form fields with Zend framework if validation has failed?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

So far I've just found out that I could write an own view helper but as I'm new to the framework I don't know how to do that. I hope there's a simpler way!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just about to ask this question myself with my own solution, to provide for the community, so to speak, when I saw you question pop up in the suggestions.

My simple and pretty elegant solution, if I say so myself, uses a simple custom decorator. It does nothing to the content it receives, but it alters the element.

```
class App_Form_Decorator_ErrorClass
    extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{

    protected $_placement = null;

    protected $_options = array(
        'class' => 'error'
    );

    public function render( $content )
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();

        if( $element->hasErrors() )
        {
            $errorClass = $this->getOption( 'class' );
            $currentClass = $element->getAttrib( 'class' );
            $element->setAttrib( 'class', ( !empty( $currentClass ) ? $currentClass . ' ' . $errorClass : $errorClass ) );
        }

        return $content;
    }
}
```

Usage:
All you need to do is add the decorator *before* the ViewHelper decorator, and your set.

```
public function init()
{
    $elementDecorators = array(
        'ErrorClass',
        'ViewHelper',
        // etc..
    );

    // or:
    $elementDecorators = array(
        array(
            'ErrorClass',
            array( 'class' => 'custom-class' ) // defaults to 'error'
        ),
        'ViewHelper',
        // etc..
    );

    // then just add the decorators to an element the way you usually do, for instance like so:
    $someElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Text( 'someElement' );
    $someElement->setDecorators( $elementDecorators );

    // etc...
```

O, PS.: Be sure to add the correct prefix path in your form:

```
$this->addPrefixPath( 'App_Form', 'App/Form' ); // or your own namespace
```

Comment: Thanks for that great answer fireeyedboy. I implemented it today in a little different way by extending the Decorator_ViewHelper instead of the Abstract class. This way it's standard for all forms with the corresponding prefixPath.

Answer (score 1):

Yes use Dojo javascript library
(although setting it up can be a little hard) 
Try this to get you started 
http://techchorus.net/add-cool-zend-dojo-date-picker-form-element-without-writing-single-line-javascript

This is how it looks : [image]

Comment: Thanks for this, but I was looking for a server side solution with ZF.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way i found to do this was extending the isValid() method of the corresponding Form Class in use, preferrably set into a My_Standard_Form Class in your library.

```
public function isValid($data)
{
    $valid = parent::isValid($data);

    foreach ($this->getElements() as $element) {
        if ($element->hasErrors()) {
            $oldClass = $element->getAttrib('class');
            if (!empty($oldClass)) {
                $element->setAttrib('class', $oldClass . ' error');
            } else {
                $element->setAttrib('class', 'error');
            }
        }
    }

    return $valid;
}
```

Credits for the solution go to the Website Factors Blog (http://www.websitefactors.co.uk/zend-framework/2011/06/error-class-on-form-field-errors-using-zend-form/).